# Under which operations are singular values invariant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, singular-values

Take a matrix A and construct B by a permutation of the columns of A. Apparently A and B have the same singular values, but I can't prove it for non 2x2 matrices.

Are there any other operations on matrices that preserve the singular values?

Comment: $B = AO$, where $O$ is an orthogonal matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying $A$ by an orthogonal matrix will necessarily preserve its singular values.

Here's an argument that proves this for square matrices. The singular values of $A$ are equal to the square roots eigenvalues of $A^TA$, which are equal to the square roots of the eigenvalues of $AA^T$. If we multiply $A$ by the left by an orthogonal matrix $U$, then we find that
$$
(UA)^T(UA) = A^TU^TUA = A^TA.
$$
Thus, the singular values of $UA$ are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $A^TA$, which are the singular values of $A$.  Similarly, if we multiply $A$ from the right by an orthogonal matrix $U$, we have
$$
(AU)(AU)^T = AUU^TA^T = AA^T.
$$
So, the singular values of $AU$ are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $AA^T$, which are the singular values of $A$.

If $U$ is a permutation matrix, then $AU$ is a matrix constructed by permuting the columns of $A$ and $UA$ is a matrix constructed by permuting the rows of $A$.

Comment: So it seems that multiplying by an orthogonal matrices will preserve the whole SVD decomposition, right?

Comment: @MarcoArmenta Not quite. It will change the matrices $U$ and $V$ in the product $A = U \Sigma V^T$.

Comment: Ah yes, I can see that. And are orthogonal matrices the only ones preserving the singular values? Or could be more?